# How to enable CORS in Asp.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, cors

I am running Angular 6 in my local and getting CROS error when invoking MVC controller action method.

I tried to fix this by adding below line of code in my .net application's web.config file.  But still getting same error.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

I do not want to run a browser by disabling web security also I do not want to create a class since only to run in my local I need to enable the CORS.

Is there any simplest of way to fix this in Web.config or Global.asax file.

Answer (score 2):

CORS requires 3 headers to work correctly.

A great resource for remembering how CORS works is [The MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

The header you have included will allow all origins to make a request. But does not specify which requests they are allowed to make, and so, all requests are blocked.
To allow all origins to make specific requests you need to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header, which tells the browser which requests the web server is allowing on that endpoint.

Depending on how your requests are formed, you may also need to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header, which tells the browser which headers it is allowed to send to the web server on that endpoint.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

Using all this, the correct configuration for your web.config would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Which will allow you to access that endpoint using either POST or GET.
The `Access-Control-Max-Age` header will tell your browser to cache these results for that many seconds, for performance reasons.

---

Also please be sure to not include this configuration in any production system you may be running.
It's always best to enable CORS explicitely for each action / controller that may need it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding below code to `Application_BeginRequest` at `Global.asax` worked for me:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:7777/");

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Use desired *urls* , *Methods* and *Headers*

Also There is no need to change anything in *Web.config*