# Icomoon fonts wont show on server

Tags: .htaccess, cors

Im trying to get icomoon fonts working. locally they work fine but on the server (sitefinity) they don't work.

I have tried using .htaccess with the following but it does not work.

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    .eot
AddType application/x-font-opentype      .otf
AddType image/svg+xml                    .svg
AddType application/x-font-ttf           .ttf
AddType application/font-woff            .woff
AddType application/font-woff2           .woff2

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(eot|otf|svg|ttf|woff2?)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This is the error i see:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: isn't the Sitefinity site hosted under IIS ?

Comment: Yes i have tried putting this into the web.config file still wont work.                                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: Ok, can you provide some more information, e.g. is this a Sitefinity page? if so, what request is the page making to the font (on what domain)?

Comment: @stephenryan The answer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57307454/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-mvc5/57318706#57318706) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused - is that .htaccess on the Sitefinity server that's hosting those fonts, or is it on *your* server (of your webpage that's trying to access the fonts from Sitefinity)?

If you're trying to access fonts on another site, it has to be *that* site that returns the ACAO response header (with the font itself).

If you can provide an example request for a font file, that might help, but TBH, CORS was pretty much designed so that people couldn't just include fonts from a 3rd-party (a 'font factory') on their own site. So I suspect that in this case, your webpage is trying to get the fonts from Sitefinity, the browser is passing the Origin request header with the GET request for the font, and Sitefinity is refusing to return the ACAO response header, so your webpage won't display the fonts.